# Fixing set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, xpath, xml-parsing

After upgrading to Postgres 12  statement

```
update temprid set
ContactFirstName =unnest(xpath(
     '/E-Document/Document/DocumentParties/BuyerParty/ContactData/ContactFirstName/text()',x))::text,
yhik =unnest(xpath(
     '/E-Document/Document/DocumentItem/ItemEntry/BaseUnit/text()',x))::text
     from t
```

throws error

> set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE

How to fix this ? 
In Postgres 9.1 it worked.
I read similar answers here but they recomment to totally overwrite statement. Maybe there is simply change which makes this statement work ?

Result should by any value of xpath expression in case if xpath returns multiple values

Update

I tried according to answer

```
update temprid set
ContactFirstName =xpath(
     '/E-Document/Document/DocumentParties/BuyerParty/ContactData/ContactFirstName/text()',x)[1]::text
```

But got error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 3: .../BuyerParty/ContactData/ContactFirstName/text()',x)[1]::text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace

```
SET col = unnest(array_value)
```

with

```
SET col = array_value[1]
```

In your case, you have to use an extra pair of parentheses, because the `array_value` is an expression:

```
SET ContactFirstName =
    (xpath(
        '/E-Document/Document/DocumentParties/BuyerParty/ContactData/ContactFirstName/text()',
        x)
    )[1]
```

Comment: I tried but this causes error `syntax error at or near "["` . I updated question. How to fix?